# Python-docx module not overwriting same file name

Tags: python, python-docx

I have been using python-docx to create and save .docx files automatically. It works to create a single uniquely named .docx file, but if I want to overwrite that file it doesn't do anything.

I have tried doing os.remove, or deleting the file before running my program again, and still nothing.

The only thing which allows it to work is to go into the Recycle Bin and delete it permanently.

```py
def writeDocx():
    # os.remove(client+' Invoice.docx')
    ###heading at top###
    document.add_heading(client+" Invoice", 0)
    document.add_paragraph("").add_run("This Invoice was generated automatically").italic = True
    table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
    t = table.rows[0].cells
    t[0].text = 'TEST'
    t[1].text = 'TEST'
    t[2].text = 'TEST'
    for i in range(6):
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        row_cells[0].text = str(i)
        row_cells[1].text = str(i)
        row_cells[2].text = str(i)
    document.save(client+' Invoice.docx')
```

It should overwrite already saved  Invoice.docx file with the newly generated file, but it does not.

It shows no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.save(filename)` will overwrite `filename` if it exists.

Your code does not show where `document` comes from, but the following should be enough to reproduce the behavior:

```
Document().save(filename)
```

I suggest you do this with a literal, like "Client Invoice.docx", which takes the name formation out of the possible causes.

If it is still problematic, I would look at permissions, like the user running `Python` is able to both read and write the file, although I suppose that would raise an exception. The other thing to check is whether the file is being written to another directory; the default directory for a Python program is sometimes not the expected one.

You should study this document for help in refining your reproducible problem statement. Often following this process helps you see where you went wrong, but in any case, gives us more of what we need to go on to help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to follow up on this. I tried it on another computer and it worked. Must have been something with Word running very secretly in the background or something.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation of [Python-Docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html?highlight=save)

> The `document.save("file.docx")` function will not replace the
>   existing file until it is opened as document object (`document = Document("file.docx")`)

But if you want a workaround, you can do something like this

```
is_present = False
document = Document()
try:
  document = Document("Invoice.docx")
  is_present =True
except:
  pass

if is_present:
  document.save("old-Invoice.docx") # or you can delete it.
  document = Document()
document.add_heading("Invoice", 0)
document.add_paragraph("").add_run("This Invoice was generated automatically").italic = True
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
t = table.rows[0].cells
t[0].text = 'TEST1'
t[1].text = 'TEST2'
t[2].text = 'TEST3'
for i in range(6):
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(i)
    row_cells[1].text = str(i)
    row_cells[2].text = str(i)
document.save('Invoice.docx')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. Also, is_present should be declared before the try just FYI.

Comment: it works for me actually & yes I missed `is_present=False document = Document() ` while copying from the ide

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists and delete it. This way you will record a new one

```
from os import remove, path

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches


if path.exists('test_doc.docx'):
    remove('test_doc.docx')

document.add_page_break()
document.save("test_doc.docx")
```